# How can I apply iter() to a pagination api?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sentinel, yield-from

I watched Raymond Hettinger's [Idiomatic Python](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OSGv2VnC0go&t=912s) talk, and learned about  the [sentinel argument](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) to `iter()`.
 I'd like to try to apply it to a piece of code I'm working on iterating over an API that uses pagination (it's Twilio, but not relevant to my question).

I have an API that returns: a list of data, and a next page URL.  When the pagination is exhausted, the next page URL returns as an empty string.  I wrote the fetching function as a generator and looks roughly like this:

```
def fetch(url):
    while url:
        data = requests.get(url).json()
        url = data['next_page_uri']
        for row in data[resource]:
            yield row
```

This code works fine, but I'd like to try to remove the `while` loop and replace it with a call to `iter()` using the `next_page_uri` value as the sentinel argument.
Alternately, could this be written with a `yield from`?

Comment: You can’t use `iter` on *part* of a value.  You could write an adapter generator, but it’d be just as complicated as what you have now.

Comment: It's worth noting that python3.6 throws a warning for the example version of the function.  In my actual code the inside of the `while` loop is in a `try`-`except to catch `StopIteration`.

Comment: You want it to *yield* rows till the `'next_page_uri'` is an empty string?  Does it need to make a new request for each *next_page*.?

Comment: Yes, as written currently, it makes a new request each time it exhausts `data[resource]` and then continues to yield additional rows from the next `request.get`.

Comment: @Sethish: What here could raise `StopIteration`?

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0479/#consequences-for-existing-code
I'm not 100% clear on the mechanics of `StopIteration`.  But the above code will generating a warning in 3.6 unless you wrap it and catch `StopIteration`.  The PEP states that this is the preferred way to make a generator with a while loop, unless I'm misunderstanding it.

Comment: Why do you need to implement this using `iter` with a sentinel?

Comment: the `for` loop will catch the `StopIteration` exception for you, that's what terminates the loop…  no need to catch it yourself

Comment: @sammason I mis-remembered when the deprecation warning was being thrown.  It only came up in my tests when I exhaust the generator with `list()` not when I use the generator in `dict_writer.writerows()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might be what you mean… but as stated in the comments, it doesn't help much:

```
def fetch_paged(url):
    while url:
        res = requests.get(url)
        res.raise_for_status()
        data = res.json()
        yield data
        url = data['next_page_uri']

def fetch(url):
    for data in fetch_paged(url):
        yield from data[resource]
```

(I've taken the opportunity to put in a call to `raise_for_status()` which will `raise` for non-successful, i.e. `res.status_code < 400`, responses)

not sure if it's any "better", but possibly if you're going to be reusing the `fetch_paged` functionality a lot

Note: lots of other APIs put this `next_page_uri` into the response headers in [standard ways](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5988.txt) which the `requests` library knows how to deal with and exposes via the [`res.links`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#link-headers) attribute

Comment: Thanks! You're right, this type of pagination doesn't quite fit the idiom that I linked in the question.
I tried `res.links` but alas, the Twilio api doesn't send their values that way:
```ipdb> data
<Response [200]>
ipdb> data.links
{}```